# Java convert user input to a specific value

Tags: java

I have a method that takes a user's input in this case "%YEAR%" and converts
that input into the current year. The getCopyrightProperty method takes a property
entered by the user and displays its output. Which works fine. But how would
I take if the user input %YEAR% and display the actually year to it along with also
displaying the user output.

```
private static final String COPYRIGHT_PROPERTY = "copyright-message";
private static final String SHOWYEAR = "" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

public String getCopyrightProperty(){                
    return (this.properties != null) ? this.properties.get(COPYRIGHT_PROPERTY, "") : null;
}

public String getSubstituteCurrYear(String in){                
    return in.replaceAll("%YEAR%", SHOWYEAR);            
}
```

Sample input would be "**%YEAR% input some placeholder text**" and ideally the output should be "**2013 input some placeholder text**"

properties.get is a sling method that gathers user input from a specific property

Comment: The question is unclear. Could you provide sample input and output? Also, what is this.properties?

Comment: @Vishy just added sample input and output

Comment: @izuriel there is no error my output is just %YEAR% input some placeholder text when it should be 2013 some placeholder text.

Comment: Just to be sure, remember that the replacement doesn't take part in the given input but in the returned value.

Comment: @DelmonYoung, output from what?  What method(s) are you calling?

Comment: @DelmonYoung So when I mocked this up in ideone I've got no issues. Check it out http://ideone.com/zbrlQp and pull from it what you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
private static final String COPYRIGHT_PROPERTY  = "%YEAR% copyright-message";
private static final String SHOWYEAR            = 
        "" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

public String getCopyrightProperty() {
    String s = this.properties.get(COPYRIGHT_PROPERTY, "");
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return getSubstituteCurrYear(s);
    }
}

public String getSubstituteCurrYear(String in) {
    return in.replaceAll("%YEAR%", SHOWYEAR);
}
```

Comment: I don't think is what he wanted. I don't see any of this in the question.